# How to get rid of phosphorus in my well water

Tags: water, well

I recently bought a house built in the mid 1960s that has its own well system. From my knowledge nothing had been updated to the well system since it had been installed. I conducted a premium water test and all of the categories seem to be within an acceptable range.

My only concern is Phosphorus came back at 52 PPM. According to EPA safe drinking water needs to have 40 PPM or less.

The water sample was collected at the kitchen sink.

The house was also vacant for a good amount of time before I bought it so it had been a while before the water had been run.

Is this something I should be concerned about and should I think about installing a water filtration system for my home?

Comment: How long was the water running before testing?  If it did not have time to flush out pipes/tanks, I would get another test for phosphorous.

Comment: Might also want to check that you don't have a antiscaling "filter" in line that's ADDING phosphates to the water, since the house is new-to-you and you collected at the sink, not from where the water enters the house.

Comment: Also, is this farmland? High phosphorus *might* be from fertilizer runoff -- a separate concern.

Answer (score 0):

Removal options for phosphorous (suitable for drinking water, there are many more for treating waste water) appear to be activated carbon and reverse osmosis filtration.